# Is the number of "workers" in Laravel Octane equal to the number of requests that can be handled simultaneously?

Tags: laravel, laravel-octane

Do I understand correctly that the number of "workers" in Laravel Octane is equal to the number of requests that can be executed simultaneously?

**For example, if there are 2 workers, and 2 of them are busy returning CSV exports - new requests will not be processed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Laravel Octane the number of workers is directly responsible for a number of requests that your app can handle simultaneously. To prove that, we can add the following route:

```php
Route::get('longrequest', function () {
    sleep(15);
    return 'done';
});
```

If you spin a Laravel Octane instance with 2 workers and hit this endpoint twice - the third execution will have to wait until one of two workers are free to process it.